# How to start the induction step for an inequality.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, induction

If $ n $ is a natural number and $n \geq 4$ then $3^n > 2n^2 +3n$. Note* The inequality is false when $ n=1,2, $ and $ 3 $. I understand how to prove the base case. I'm having trouble proving the induction step for $  P(k+1) $ . I'm not sure how to get $ (k+1) $ on both sides to prove the inequality is true. Any ideas on how to get started? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $3^n > 2n^2 + 3n$ for some natural $n \ge 4$. Then you want to prove that $3^{n+1} > 2(n+1)^2 + 3(n+1)=2n^2+4n+2+3n+3=2n^2+3n+4n+5$. 
 
Hence, you just need to prove that $2(3)^n>4n+5 $ for all $n \ge 4$, after you have completed your base case.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(n)$ be the statement $(n\in \Bbb N \land 3^n>2n^2+3n).$ We have $$S(n)\implies 3^n\geq 2n^2+3n+1\implies$$ $$\implies 3^{n+1}=3\cdot 3^n\geq 3(2n^2+3n+1).$$  Now we also have $$3(2n^2+3n+1)>2(n+1)^2+3(n+1)\iff $$ $$\iff 6n^2+9n+3>2n^2+7n+5\iff$$ $$\iff 4n^2+2n>2,$$ and this last inequality holds for all $n\in \Bbb N.$ So for all $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $S(n) \implies 3^{n+1}\geq 3(2n^2+3n+1)>$ $>2(n+1)^2+3(n+1).$

That is, $S(n)\implies S(n+1).$

Comment: We do not really need to strengthen $3^n>2n^2+3n$ to $3^n\geq 2n^2+3n+1$ because $3(2n^2+3n)>2(n_1)^2+3(n+1)\iff 4n^2+2n>5 ,$  and this last inequality hold for all $n\in \Bbb N.$ But it is a useful tool in other Q's.